# Jenkins UI : Read from properties File

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a job and select Extended Choice Parameters option, where in the Parameter Type I select is Multi-Level Multi Select. It asks me for a property file. I have a normal Maven workspace , wherein I have included a certain test.properties file in the basedir of the project. However I am not sure how to retrieve the same in the Jenkins UI.

It does not take any path. I am new to Jenkins. How can we read properties from a file, directly into Jenkins UI for Extended Choice Parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can add property file by EnvInject plugin
See http://www.360logica.com/blog/how-to-change-the-data-into-properties-file-using-jenkins/